# Tableview with custom cell is not working in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios7

I am working on a iOS7 application , I am presenting a modal view controller which contains a table view with custom cell. Custom cell contains a `label` and a `textfield`.

For iOS6 , my code is working perfect, but when I am running my application in iOS7 iPad, `tableview` delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` does not get called.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure application presenting the empty table view? is numberofrowinsection delegate method get fired?

Comment: Hi Ganapathy ... Yes , All other delegate methods are getting called .. in iOS7 .

Comment: is Selection working fine in IOS 6?

Comment: Yes , In iOS6 , everything is working fine . all delegates methods are getting  called.

Comment: Update question with cell_for_row_at_index_path code block.

Comment: Which sdk do you link to ? iOS 7 or ios6 ? A quick fix would be to use iOS 6 sdk.